# specify view's column type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I have a view in `SQL Server` and there is a column with `NULL` value. I am setting a `NULL` because I am going to use `UNION` clause with another table later on.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myview] (a,b,c)
AS
SELECT a,b,NULL;
```

It seems that somehow the type of column `c` is `INTEGER`. I need to be able to set it to `NVARCHAR`.

How can I change that column type to `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: Why you are setting the `NULL` value in the `view`. You can add it later when the `UNION` clause is used and keep the view clear off unnecessary columns. For example: `SELECT *, NULL FROM my_view UNION ...`

Comment: @gotqn - While you're correct in this case, your claim won't hold in all cases involving views and NULL values (Or any other static value). A view can be thought of (and used as) an abstraction layer. As such it's perfectly suitable to hide that fact that a specific column is always NULL until a "new implementation" generates other values for the relevant column(s) and no modification is required in code that uses the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `CAST`:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myview] (a,b,c)
AS
SELECT a,b,CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(100)) c;
```

Comment: The alias clause "(a,b,c)" is redundant in your example.

Comment: @gen-y-s It's there in the OP, I didn't touch that. The entire statement is "wrong" - `SELECT a,b,c` can't work without a `FROM` clause, but I didn't touch that either. I answered the question, no more & no less. Regarding your comment though... well, I disagree, having the column names improves readability and makes sure the "contract" is kept between implementation (view) and use (other statements for example). Also, your comment contributes nothing to the OP, nor to my answer - it's redundant.

Comment: My comment was meant to highlight a flaw in your example which may confuse people. Specifically, the view column name list "(a,b,c)" after the view name does indeed improve readability, and it was actually REQUIRED in example given by the OP since the NULL value in the query doesn't have an alias. But in your example the CAST expression does have an alias (WHY??? Either that or the column name list is redundant)

Comment: @gen-y-s again, the query itself is incomplete, it can't work as it is written, and I COMPLETELY DISAGREE with you (see that, I know capital letters as well). When you have a long list of columns, it helps a great deal if all of them have meaningful names, and it helps a great deal if you have a list of names readily available for quick reference. And also, there's no flaw at all in the example other than the one I described myself (lack of FROM clause). The rest is perfectly legal, and doesn't even have any impact on performance. It's nothing more than  a matter of taste.